# Element-wise addition (multiplication, exponentiation, etc.) of lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary

If I have two lists of identical size in Haskell

```
list1 = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
list2 = [3.0,5.0,7.0]
```

how would I perform element-wise addition to create a third list of equal size?

```
[4.0,7.0,10.0]
```

Specifically, I want to make a function like this:

```
listAdd :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
listAdd a b
    | length a /= length b = error "length mismatch"
    otherwise              = ????
```

I can't figure out what to put in place of '????'.  I think it must involve 'map', and some version of '+', but the partial evaluation thing is confusing me, and the correct syntax has proved elusive.

EDIT 1:

I thought I understood the pattern matching with the cons operator, so I tried this next:

```
listAdd :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
listadd (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x+y) : listAdd xs ys
listAdd []     []     = []
listAdd _      _      = error "length mismatch"
```

But there is still something wrong, as

```
listAdd [1.0,2.0] [2.0,3.0]
```

goes right past the useful patterns and returns an error.

EDIT 2:

With the typo eliminated,

```
listAdd :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
listAdd (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x+y) : listAdd xs ys
listAdd []     []     = []
listAdd _      _      = error "length mismatch"
```

works as advertised.  As managing types for tensors of arbitrary dimension is beyond me at this early point in my studies, I decided to merely extend it to matrix addition:

```
mAdd :: [[Float]] -> [[Float]] -> [[Float]]
mAdd (x:xs) (y:ys) = listAdd x y : mAdd xs ys
mAdd []     []     = []
mAdd _      _      = error "length mismatch"
```

I realize it's probably not ideal to tie the functions together, as it reduces modularity/portability, but it does what I need it to do.

EDIT 3:

I hope it's not premature to declare that some degree of learning has occurred.  I now have this:

```
listCombine :: (Float -> Float -> Float) -> [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
listCombine f (x:xs) (y:ys) = (f x y) : listCombine f xs ys
listCombine f []     []     = []
listCombine _ _      _      = error "length mismatch"
```

which is probably identical to zipWith, except that it gives an error for mismatched lengths.  It handled the corner cases I threw at it with expected results.

Comment: Although you can use explicit recursion like you did, the more idiomatic Haskell version would just be ``zipWith (+)`` in the case where the lists are of equal length.

Comment: In this case, I'd like to do it the long way.  My hope is that after getting it to work with lists, I will see how to extend it for element-wise addition of tensors of arbitrary size.  Any idea why the function I have doesn't work?

Comment: @user2790167 you have a typo: `listadd (x:xs) (y:ys) =` should be `listAdd (x:xs) (y:ys) =`. I guess you didn't copy-paste the code that I posted but retyped it instead.

Comment: I can't believe I typed that wrong.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: if it's more than just one function, as the first step you can abstract over the operation in use, to replace the current `listAdd` with `listCombine (+)` (whatever the name you choose); then `mAdd = listCombine (listCombine (+))` is the short definition for `mAdd` without the code replication.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write listCombine.  I understand it would take three arguments, but I don't know how to 'reuse' an argument in the body of the function.  Do I just make patterns for every possible operator, like `listCombine (+) (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x+y) : listCombine (+) xs ys` and `listCombine (*) (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x*y) : listCombine (*) xs ys` ?

Comment: OK, I think I figured it out.  You pattern match to an unspecified function f using `listCombine f (x:xs) (y:ys) = (f x y) : listCombine f xs ys`.

Comment: And if I understand this correctly, the type signature would be `listCombine :: (Float -> Float -> Float) -> [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]`, unless I need to account for the fact that operator f might accept multiple types...

Comment: good! :) so for multiple types the signature is `listCombine :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`. This type is polymorphic:  it'll work for any type `a`, by using the same type everywhere `a` is mentioned. `a` is a *type variable*. One time it'll be `a ~ Float`, and another - `a ~ [Float]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separately calculating the argument lists' length is a bad idea. We usually want to consume as little of the input as possible while producing as much of output as possible. This is known as "not forcing the input too much", i.e. being as lazy as possible.

In your case, when we analyze the two arguments we'll know about the length mismatch if one list is empty and the other isn't:

```
listAdd :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
listAdd (x:xs) (y:ys) =  (x+y) : listAdd ... ...
listAdd []     []     = []
listAdd _      _      =  error "length mismatch"
```

This way it will work even for infinite lists.

The built-in function similar to this is `zipWith`, but it ignores the list length mismatch:

```
Prelude> zipWith(+) [1,2] [3]
[4]
```

It is equivalent to the above definition with the last two lines replaced with the catch-all clause

```
listAdd _      _      = []
```

Comment: I follow the laziness idea, but what is the second line of your function doing?  The : bits are mysterious to me.

Comment: `:` on the left hand side of equations are part of a pattern: `(x:xs)` matches a non-empty list with head `x` and tail `xs`. On the right hand side it's a list constructor: `x:xs` describes a list with head `x` and tail `xs`.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't address the original question but one of the comments: addition of tensors. My understanding of tensors is as n-dimensional matrices. You already know that element-wise addition is just an application of `zipWith`. But we can write the function `addLists` using the applicative and functor typeclasses:

```
import Control.Applicative

addLists :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
addLists x y = (*) <$> x <*> y
```

or equivalently:

```
addLists :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
addLists = liftA2 (*)
```

Note that `<$> == fmap` and `<*>` is in the `Applicative` class.

First we define a type for rank-0 tensors:

```
newtype Identity a = Identity {getIdentity :: a}

instance Functor Identity where 
  fmap f (Identity a) = Identity (f a) 

instance Applicative Identity where 
  pure a = Identity a
  (<*>) (Identity f) (Identity a) = Identity (f a)
```

Then a type for adding a new layer on top of a rank-n tensor, creating a rank n+1 tensor:

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose {getCompose :: f (g a)}

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where 
  fmap f (Compose a) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) a)

instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where 
  pure a = Compose (pure (pure a))
  (<*>) (Compose f) (Compose a) = Compose (liftA2 (<*>) f a)
```

But wait, there's more! These type and their instances are already defined for you, namely in `Data.Functor.Identity` and `Data.Functor.Compose`. You can now write generic tensor element-wise addition:

```
addTensor :: Applicative f => f Float -> f Float -> f Float
addTensor = liftA2 (*)
```

The function `liftA2` just generalizes `zipWith` to `Applicative`s. For rank-1 you have:

```
addTensor1 :: Compose [] Identity Float -> Compose [] Identity Float -> Compose [] Identity Float
addTensor1 = addTensor
```

This type is a bit noisy. You can easily define type synonyms:

```
type Tensor0 = Identity
type Tensor1 = Compose [] Tensor0
type Tensor2 = Compose [] Tensor1
type Tensor3 = Compose [] Tensor2
type Tensor4 = Compose [] Tensor3
```

Then:

```
addTensor3 :: Tensor3 Float -> Tensor3 Float -> Tensor3 Float
addTensor3 = addTensor

addTensor4 :: Tensor4 Float -> Tensor4 Float -> Tensor4 Float
addTensor4 = addTensor
```

Since `addTensor` abstracts over all `Applicative`s you may want to define a subclass of `Applicative` which form valid tensors:

```
class Applicative t => Tensor t 
instance Tensor Identity
instance Tensor t => Tensor (Compose [] t)

addTensor :: Tensor f => f Float -> f Float -> f Float
addTensor = liftA2 (*)
```

I suspect you may have other operations on tensors other than addition. This general form makes it very easy to define a large range of operations. But hypothetically if you only wanted `addTensor` you could do something like:

```
class Tensor a where 
  addTensor :: a -> a -> a 

instance Tensor Float where 
  addTensor = (+)

instance Tensor t => Tensor [t] where 
  addTensor = zipWith addTensor
```

Much simpler types result: `addTensor :: [[[[Float]]]] -> [[[[Float]]]] -> [[[[Float]]]]` for rank-4.

Comment: I suspect it will take me a while to understand this answer, but thank you.

Comment: You have `addTensor = liftA2 (*) `. You probably mean `(+)` rather than `(*)` or alternatively `multTensor`.

Comment: I think the second occurence of `<$>` in your first code snippet should be `<*>`!